# How can I fill element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a modal (bootstrap modal) as string when you click button with jquery and I have two option class in my modal is

`Call Today` and `Call Tomorrow` it's okey so far.

and my modal has been creating when you clicked the button so that's why I added two attribute to my button is `data-open-hours` and `data-closed-hours` and I want to explain what I want with an example:

for example:

my `data-open-hours` is : `09:00`
my `data-closed-hours` : `22:00`

then fill my `.when-call` select from `09:00` to `22:00` with `Call Now` option

so if you choose `Call Tomorrow` then fill my select from `09:00` to `22:00` without `Call Now` string.

My working example:

```js
function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {
  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today">Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="form-control"><option class="call-now">Call Now</option></select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  var openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  var closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/awvgRb)

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you really need. You have two selects here. The first one with "Call Today" and the second one with "Call Now". Try to elaborate on what happens when you select each of the options are selected and possible let us know what and where the output has to be displayed.

Comment: @JoeyEzekiel thanks for replying and sorry about my bad english.. I'm just trying to fill my select with option from `data-open-hours` to `data-closed-hours` value..that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems with this code, like the fact that your `select` has no name, your `option`s have no value, and most `class`es seem like they should be `id`s instead... I would suggest reviewing these parts.

Working with what you have at the moment, anyway, and supposing you want to add an option for every hour from opening to closure, you should:
- fill the second `select` with the correct options, parsing your open/close times;
- add a listener on `change` for the first `select` to add/remove the "Call now" `option`

This should work, even if it's quite rough

```js
function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {
  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today">Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6">';
  html = html + '<select class="hour-call form-control">'+getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true)+'</select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  var openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  var closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});

function callNow() {
  return '<option class="call-now">Call Now</option>';
}

function getOptions(open, close, now) {
  var options = now ? callNow() : '';
  console.log(open,close,now);
  // get open/close time as hours only
  var start = open.split(':')[0];
  var end = close.split(':')[0];
  // using +start will convert to a base 10 number - avoiding the problem that numbers with a leading zero are octal numbers
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
  }
  return options;
}

$(document).on("change", ".when-call", function(event) {
  // not the most efficient way, but you can always remove 'Call now', then add it back only if needed
  $(".hour-call .call-now").remove();
  if($('.call-today').is(':selected')) 
    $('.hour-call').prepend(callNow());
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great..can we make this  `Call at 09:00 - 10:00`,`10:000 - 11:00` ? very well

Comment: Of course you can. In the loop we are working with numbers, so you can easily change that.

E.g. `for (var h = +start; h < +end; h++) { options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00 - '+(h+1)+':00</option>' }`

**EDIT**: if you also need to left-pad with 0, it can be done in a few ways, e.g. with [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: I see a little bug (so if it's a bug) after select a time if you select Call tomorrow you will see second select option is not change (at least it's not selected first value)

Comment: The question was only about filling the `select`, not pre-selecting an option ;)

Comment: You can still do that at the end of the `change` listener, using [jQuery select](https://api.jquery.com/select/) for your chosen option